# Using PyCharm IDE to work within a pre-made virtual environment

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn Flask following [this guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/). I followed the instructions and created a virtual environment in `/Users/user1/project/venv` and installed Flask while in the virtual environment. I did this using the *terminal* in macOS.

I now want to use the *PyCharm IDE* to work within this virtual environment. How do I do this?

The folder `project` has two files: `app` and `venv`. The `venv` folder has four files: `bin`, `include`, `lib`, and `pyvenv.cfg`. Where am I supposed to be working in (that is, creating Python scripts)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change your Python interpreter by providing the path to the Python executable inside your desired venv. There you can specify that you have an existing environment.  Have a look at this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-interpreter.html

Comment: The venv folder should be left untouched, your dependencies will be installed there. You want to work inside the app folder. I would suggest to have a look at the mega tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world because it provides information about a well structured project

Comment: @e.Fro I'm not sure what you're referring to. See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is perfectly fine. I recommend that you create the start script in `project` and keep the remaining code contained to `app`. Your interaction with the project could then look like this:

```
~$ cd project/
~/project$ ls
app/              requirements.txt  start.py          tests/            venv/
~/project$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) ~/project$ pip install -r requirements.txt
(venv) ~/project$ FLASK_APP=start.py flask run
```

To configure PyCharm to use this virtual environment, open the project settings and set your `venv`'s `python` executable as *Python interpreter* for your project.

Comment: What is a "start script"? And why do I need it?

Comment: You have to tell your application server what it should do. This could be as simple as `from app import create_app; app = create_app()` if you're using the [application factory pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/). Other servers would take an executable, for example starting [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn) with `gunicorn "app:create_app()"`. It all depends on your project setup how you have to instruct your server to serve your application.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm still at the beginning of the tutorial, so I'm unfamiliar with all of this. I have edited my post with another image.

Comment: Select the radio button _Existing interpreter_ and direct the value for `Interpreter:` to `/Users/user1/project/venv` to use the manually created virtual environment.

Comment: I cannot select the `venv` folder; but I can select files. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry, that was an inaccurate instruction. Please select `/Users/user1/project/venv/bin/python` (or `python3`) and click "OK".

Comment: Ok, done. So do I just work inside `app`? Do I need to activate the virtual environment or anything in PyCharm?

Comment: PyCharm automatically uses the interpreter's environment. You can now either install additional libraries via PyCharm or by activating `venv` and installing them via `pip install`. The rest can then happen inside `app`, yes.